# stub method with other method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 #...
 def my_method
   {:created_at => self.created_at, :words => self.text.split.find_by{/*my_conditiond_here*/}}
 end
 #...
end
```

Controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
 #...
 def my_action
   posts = Post.where(params[:conditions])
   @words = posts.map{|post| post.my_method}.flatten
 end
 #...
end
```

But when I try to make tests for it, i got some troubles.

```
it "returns words for single post" do
  post = FactoryGirl.create :post, :text => 'any text here'
  get :my_action
  expect(assigns[:words]).to eq(post.my_method)
end
```

I get something like that:

> ```
>    expected: [{:words=>["any", "text", "here"], :created_at=>2013-11-12 09:33:04 UTC}]
>         got: [{"words"=>["any", "text", "here"], "created_at"=>2013-11-12 09:33:04 UTC}]
> ```

More than that, if I use

```
  expect(assigns[:words].first).to eq(post.my_method.fitst.with_indifferent_access)
```

it fails:

> ```
>    expected: {"words"=>["any", "text", "here"], "created_at"=>2013-11-12 09:33:04 UTC}
>         got: {"words"=>["any", "text", "here"], "created_at"=>2013-11-12 09:33:04 UTC}
>    (compared using ==)
>
>    Diff:
> ```

By experimenting, I realized that problem in `created_at` element.

It looks like it possible to stub `my_method` but I don't know how to return value connected to object. For example id.
Or suggest please better way to test `my_action`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do either one of the following, but with preference towards the second solution (message expecations):

1. Check only the `words` array, and not a timestamp such as `created_at`.
2. Encapsulate all of the `Post::where` and `#map` calls into a descriptive class/singleton method on `Post`, and check that `Post` receives the correct message.  This way, you are only checking that the right message gets passed to Post, rather than testing both Post and the controller.

In other words, for solution #2 above, you might have this:

**post.rb:**

```
class Post
  def self.posts_with_my_method params
    # move code from controller here
  end
end
```

**tasks_controller.rb:**

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
 #...
  def my_action
    @words = Post.posts_with_my_method params(params)
  end
  #...
 end
```

**spec:**

```
it "returns words for single post" do
  Post.should_receive(:posts_with_my_method).and_return([:foo])
  get :my_action
  expect(assigns[:words]).to eq([:foo])
end
```